# SQL Server Snapshot Replication error 22018

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication, sql-server-2016

I am trying to get snapshot replication between two MSSQL servers to work but am receiving errors. Any help will be much appreciated!

My setup:
Publisher/Distributor: SQL 2008 R2
Subscriber: SQL 2016

I am just trying it with a simple test table named Cars containing:

```
Car_ID   Car_Name
1   Hummer
2   Porsche
3   Tesla
4   Bently
5   Lotus Elise
6   Mini
```

In the Replication Monitor I get the following errors:

> Error messages: The process could not bulk copy into table
>   '"dbo"."Cars"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20037)
>   Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20037 metadata query failed Invalid
>   character value for cast specification (Source: MSSQLServer, Error
>   number: 22018) Get help: http://help/22018 Unspecified error

Answer (score 0):

Right click to related database and click to Options then check compatibility level is same or not ?
If not choose same level as publication side.